# Convert model to "skeleton / prototype" model for quick real world "Proof of Concept"

Tags: fusion360, rapid-prototyping

Does anyone know of a method, app, technique to "dumb down", if you will, larger models to do a quick initial print to check that it fits the real world proof of concept that it was designed for.

I am not talking about 0.3 mm draft printing, I already do that... But is there a way or method, to kind of "skeleton" the large print, print it in let's say, 25 % of the actual time to test its physical application. Scaling down works, in some situations, but I would prefer a 100 % model, just "simplified / skeleton'ized", still with the correct dimensions.

I primarily use Fusion360 for designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are techniques to remove material from an exiting model to create less dense models (like in a skeleton). One such a technique is applying Voronoi tessellation (also known as a Voronoi decomposition, a Voronoi partition, or a Dirichlet tessellation), basically the model is broken up in polyhedrons of which the ribs are kept with a certain thickness and smoothed. See e.g. the following example from https://www.voronator.com/:

[image]

You can modify files yourself or use an [online application](https://www.voronator.com/) to do that for you.

However, you may create skeleton like models, but it is not always faster to print these models; they may have less material, but retraction may cause the printing time to be actually longer than printing the original at low density infill.